# threading.Thread not working but _thread does

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have some legacy python 2.7 code that use wxPython to create a gui. The gui code uses `_thread.start_new_thread` to kick off an imported function from another module. We are transitioning this code to python 3.9 and I want to replace `_thread` with `threading.Thread` so I can use the `thread.excepthook`. However when I replaced `_thread` with `threading.Thread` my code just hangs.

For example I had:

```
import _thread
import custom_module

_thread.start_new_thread(custom_module.go, (arg1, arg2))
```

Where the `custom_module` has a function go that executes. This works fine in both Python 3.9 but I am trying to use `threading.excepthook` so I am trying to replace it with this:

```
import threading
import custom_module

threading.Thread(target=custom_module.go, args=(arg1, arg2)).start()
```

But when my code gets to the thread it just hangs.

Is there some difference between `_thread` and `threading` that would cause a thread to hang on `threading` but not `_thread`?

Additionally in Python 2.7 I was using `sys.excepthook` to manage exceptions happening in the threads, but that is no longer working. When an exception occurs in the thread, the thread just ends. Any thoughts?

=================================================================
So it looks like the issue is not that threading.Thread is not working.  I am able to get a print statement to execute at the beginning of my custom_module.go function.  It is actually hanging on a logger.info statement for a logger that is substantiated in the main program.

```
def init_logger():
    """Initialize."""
    logger = logging.getLogger('FDS')
    logger.setLevel('INFO')
    logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d | %(levelname)-8s |' +
                                  ' %(name)s | %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%Y/%j-%H:%M:%S')

    # set up log buffers (will flush into log file & GUI once started)
    mh_file = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(capacity=1000, flushLevel='DEBUG')
    mh_file.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(mh_file)

    mh_gui = logging.handlers.MemoryHandler(capacity=1000, flushLevel='DEBUG')
    mh_gui.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(mh_gui)

    logger.info('=' * 80)
    logger.info('Starting FDS - Release ' + __version__ + '...')

    # create application
    logger.info('Building GUI...')
    app = wx.App(False)
    logger.debug('FDS GUI application created.', extra={'same_line':True})
```

And my code hangs on

```
def go()
    logger.info('Performing input validation...')
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Have you determined that it definitely hangs on the thread call, rather than inside `custom_module.go`? Can you share the `go` function?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Changing two things (Python version, thread support) at once is also something to reconsider.

Comment: @KacperFloriański  I thought I had determined that it was hanging at the thread call as I have logging occurring at at the beginning of the go function.  But when I put a simple print statement first I learned that it was hanging at my logger.  It looks like _thread allows me to use my logger (substantiated in my primary thread) while threading.Thread does not.

Comment: Yeah, we will need to see your logger and rest of the code to determine what's wrong (to reproduce) - unless you can debug on your own from now on, since threading is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was overriding threading.excepthook with a function that I had previously used to override sys.excepthook and I hadn't changed the arguments of the function (assuming that the arguments will stay the same).  However, in threading.excepthook override functions you can only provide a single argument (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).  When I fixed that my threading was able to work and handle errors properly.